# git pull remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, pull

I have issues making a pull from a gitlab repo.  I've previously been able to use my repo with no issues (so the keys and rights are correct).

I've seen other questions answers and I've checked the time out but this fails in less than a second, also I doubt this is is a buffer issue as my repo is less than 10 mb but I've increased the buffer nonetheless.

As a reference the issue comes after a conflict. e.g. I'm trying to do a push and there are conflicts thus I'm doing a pull first.

Any ideas what the actual issue might be? and how to solve it?

```
$ git pull
fatal: git fetch-pack: expected ACK/NAK, got '?
0038ACK aa6e2684e997c306919b550fc79fb36424e70901 common
0031ACK aa6e2684e997c306919b550fc79fb36424e70901
0020?Counting objects: 5, done.
0028?Compressing objects:  50% (1/2)   ?0028?Compressing objects: 100% (2/2)   ?002c?Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
1234?PACK'
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: I would try to move your local repo to another machine and try the `pull` again there or create a new local repo using `clone` and try pull on it. Simply try to exclude possible root causes one by one - your local repo, your machine, etc.

Comment: Thanks Dawid  it's probably the machine as other users can still use it, but I need to sort it out, I can't just reformat and reinstall the computer.     clone is also failing on the machine at the moment.  (I'm able to download the tar.gz via the web interface though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a transport issue so it's difficult to identify from the client side.
In my case it was a new proxy put in the middle, others have highlighted load balancers e.g. nginx.   So, if you have the same issue, it's time to talk to your network people.     This is not Git's fault but they could have a more friendly message.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, resetting my old repository's SSH key (Access Key) fixed the issue

in bitbucket:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

in gitlab:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#generate-an-ssh-key-pair